# Android AdRequest returns only onAdFailedToLoad AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

Tags: android, admob

My application has been on the Google Play store for a month and everything was working fine. Two days ago I added it to the "Designed for families" category. I received acceptance and congratulations from the Google team. Since this, my Interstitials have stopped showing. I receive `AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL`.

```
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;   
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true); 

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .build();
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(InterstitialSample.AD_UNIT_ID);
interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.d("Tim", "OK");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            String message = String.format("onAdFailedToLoad (%s)", InterstitialSample.getErrorReason(errorCode));
            Log.d("Tim", message);
        }
    });
```

I didn't change the package name. Also, I tried changing the `AD_UNIT_ID` with no success.

Comment: My app was receiving ads correctly. After I added "is_designed_for_families" parameter, the app is not receiving ads anymore. Instead I receive "No fill from ad sever, failed to load ad: 3". Did you solved this issue?

Comment: It is not a bug. Just a few ads has characteristics "for children 5 years" or "for children 8 years". Remove your app from "Design for families" category for showing ads or wait until there will be advertising with similar characteristics.

Comment: Hello,  do you have issues with AdMob Design For Families Ads a 1 year after? Does your fill rate still 5% or maybe AdMob fix that issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug. Just a few ads has characteristics "for children 5 years" or "for children 8 years". Remove your app from "Design for families" category for showing ads or wait until there will be advertising with similar characteristics.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. I think you're receiving a genuine "no fill" response.

Ads that are deemed as child- and family-friendly are a subset of the broader ads pool. If you show ads today, after opting-in to the Designed for Families program, you might notice fewer filled impressions and lower revenue. We're working on increasing the pool of ads that are eligible to serve to DFF apps.

Comment: The fact that I get an error every time, without exception. That is not simply lower the number of impressions. Requests are sent as before, but no hits at all. People from different countries (Canada, USA, Mexico, Japan, Russia, Kazakhstan, Pakistan, Ukraine, Belarus, the United Arab Emirates).

Comment: @TimKruichkov I suspect the restrictions for ads able to be shown to apps designed for families are quite restrictive. It is one of the reasons I have not proceeded down that path.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue with regular banner ads:
In April 17th I added the app to the new "Designed for Families" program with settings:
Family Category: Education, Age Group: Ages 5 & Under, Ages 6-8, Displaying Ads: Yes
I checked the requirements and ad policies - my app is compliant.
The app was successfully approved by Google Developer team.

After opening the case in Admob, they asked me to add in source the code  that sets "is_designed_for_families" to true and calls the tagForChildDirectedTreatment() method for ad requests served to a child audience. Upon seeing both"is_designed_for_families" and tagForChildDirectedTreatment() set to true, AdMob will return Designed for Families-compliant ads for that ad request.
I did it, but nothing changes - still receiving "No fill from ad server."

Since April it is near two months my app received ZERO ads.
It seems that the pool of kids friendly ads is empty.
I am still waiting for issue to be resolved.

I think that the problem is that Admob did not included the "Designed for Families" category in ads campaign at all!!!
I personally checked it and did not seen this option when setting advertising campaign!

Comment: I also added with settings: Family Category: Education, Age Group: Ages 5 & Under, Ages 6-8. Like result -  "No fill from ad server."
After that I changed settings "For all ages" and filling increased - now filling equals 5 adds every 100 requests. 
So, like temporary variant is not using Age Group: Ages 5 & Under, Ages 6-8.

Comment: It really works! I changed to "Age Group: Mixed Audience"  and now it has 99% fill rate.

Comment: You are welcome. 
I'm interesed how percents of fill rate do you have in countries, like Russia, Ukraine?

Comment: Russia fill rate for "Designed for families" - it is very low ~2%. My apps are fortunately worldwide (at least English, French, German, Spanish,Portuguese,Italian,Russian, Hebrew) , Russia has just small part of my user base.

Comment: thank you for your answer, because my app aimed at Russia and I see low fill rate

Comment: I have the same problem (no fill and designed for families app). I've just tried to set mixed audience in families settings...how long did you have to wait for admob to start showing ads in your app? Thanks

Comment: Hi @kindergarten. Ads are appearing while having "is_designed_for_families" in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think missing this

```
/**
 * Called when leaving the activity
 */
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

/**
 * Called when returning to the activity
 */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.resume();
    }
}

/**
 * Called before the activity is destroyed
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```