# Application not receiving any Ads

Tags: android, google-ad-manager

I have multiple applications using this Ad service (Google Ads Manager). One of my app (ID: com.inscxxxxxx.abc) is not receiving the Ads starting from November last year I guess. I keep getting error messages "ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL" whenever I make any Ads request in that app.

Until last week, when I renamed the app's ID to another different ID, the Ads is showing up again. Also, I have tried renamed another app's ID to "com.inscxxxxxx.abc", same error code is shown and the Ads are gone.

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748636/android-adrequest-returns-only-onadfailedtoload-adrequest-error-code-no-fill

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have removed my app from "Design for families" category. Normally how long do the ads will show up? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Actually I don't know. Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Nope. Still not able to get any Ads but thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: hi I'm facing the same issue, have you found any solutions to this?

Comment: Nope. Still looking for solutions. =(

Comment: Damn, alright then, thanks for letting me know